# Updating timer on web page and also persisting time elapsed -- How to approach?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and trying to get used to the stateless paradigm. I want to find out how to approach keeping track of the time the user spends on the page.

I am having trouble deciding where the Timer object should reside.

On the one hand I could have this time tracking functionality on the client side, implemented in some Java Script module. This would make sense because I want the time to be displayed and updated in real time on the UI (like a normal clock ticking), but I am concerned that the scripts would stop working if the user switches tabs. On the other hand, to avoid this problem I could move the timing mechanism on the server side and update the UI using AJAX calls, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach.

In addition to displaying it on the UI I also want to persist this information. So can anyone give me some hints as to how to approach this problem given the stateless paradigm of the web applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to implement the logic for persisting time.
There is no one right/best way to implement the timer showing on web page. 
Implementing it on client side using JavaScript, or implementing it on the server side then use Ajax to call 
for showing the timer on the Web pages are all okay. But the two methods require more work.

I prefer to use ASP.NET SignalR and knockout.js to implement the timing mechanism. 
SignalR is a library for adding real-time web functionality to applications. 
Using SignalR you can have server code push content to connected clients instantly.
Knockout is a javaScript MVVM framework, it provides automatic UI refresh and two way data binding, etc.
You can get real time values on the server, then use SignalR to push the time values to clients.
Knockout can get the values and auto refresh the timer values.

If you're interested in this method, you can learn more at below:

**SignalR**

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr

**Knockout**

http://knockoutjs.com/